# How to update specific column using fgetcsv

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I'm trying to update a specific column through `fgetcsv`. But the problem is all the data are the same. Can someone help me about this? I don't know how to make the use of `grade_id` here because there are no `grade_id` in csv only in the database. And im doing it with only just file uploading.

Here's the csv. I just only want the midterm grade to be updated. But only the value `64` is inserted.
[image]

here's the result. The output should be `75,80,64` not `64,64,64`
[image]

here's my database structure 
[image]

here's my code

```
  if(isset($_POST["Import"])){

        $term = $_POST['term'];
        $fac_code = $_POST['fac_code'];
        $sch_year = $_POST['schoolyear'];
        $section = $_POST['sec'];
        $semester = $_POST['semester'];
        $sub = $_POST['sub'];

        echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

            $heading = true;
         if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
         {

            $file = fopen($filename, "r");
             while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {
                 if($heading) {
                    // unset the heading flag
                    $heading = false;
                    // skip the loop
                    continue;
                }
               //to get the last column
                $last = end($emapData);

                     $sql1 ="SELECT * FROM grade WHERE subj_descr ='$sub' AND section = '$section'";
                         $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);

                         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                         $gradeid = $row['grade_id'];

                         $sql = "UPDATE grade SET midterm_grade = '$last' WHERE grade_id = '$grade_id'";
                                   $result = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
                     }



             }
             fclose($file);
             //throws a message if data successfully imported to mysql database from excel file
             echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
                        window.location = \"homefaculty.php\"
                    </script>";



             //close of connection
            mysqli_close($con); 



         }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop for updating in mysql is done just after your fetch your last value
In means in your code you do 3 loops for updating all value

`$sql1 ="SELECT * FROM grade WHERE subj_descr ='$sub' AND section = '$section'";`

This loop which fetch always the same result is called 3 times.

`"UPDATE grade SET midterm_grade = '$last' WHERE grade_id = '$grade_id'";`

In this query the grade_id comes from all the resultset

Basically you are doing this
1- get the last value of the line of CSV
2- select all records
3- update all of them with the value of 1-
4- next line

Instead of looping in all you mysql database for the SELECT, you should be able to SELECT just the record you need. I don't know if your CSV is full but do you have the grade_id in a column ? Otherwise how can you match a row of your CSV to a record in your database ?

EDIT

after discussion you said you have a unique key on section, term and subject
(You have to identify a relation between a row in CSV and a row in your database)

```
$last = end($emapData); //to get the last column
$section = $emapData[0]; // assuming section is the first column of CSV
$term = $emapData[1]; // assuming term is the 2nd column of CSV
$subject = $emapData[2]; // assuming subject is the 3rd column of CSV

$sql = "UPDATE grade SET midterm_grade = '$last' WHERE section = '$section' AND term = '$term' AND subject = '$subject'";
$result = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
```

Comment: Every row have an grade_id sir. I don't know how to use the grade_id for that.

Comment: All of the record are needed sir. Every .csv contains a section of student. I don't know how to update it with just one go.

Comment: You confirm that you do have a grade_id in the csv ?

Comment: Yes. I post the structure of my database to my question.

Comment: I don't see the grade_id in csv that's why I ask

Comment: But how can i use the grade_id if it's just only a file_upload?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how getting the grade_id from CSV then use it directly in your UPDATE query. But I asked you about grade_id in CSV and you always answer about your database which is useless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122152/discussion-between-sylwit-and-nethken).